# How do I change position of a hide/show div depending on which trigger link is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, position, hide, show

I have a content div that contains a client's social profile links. Both the top navigation and footer navigation contain links that I would like to trigger this panel.

If the top navigation link is clicked, I would like the panel to appear under that top link.

If the footer navigation link is clicked, I would like the panel to appear just above that footer link.

How can I accomplish this?

An example can be shown here:

http://landmarkdenver.com/

See? If you click the connect icon (next to the Select Country dropdown), the panel appears
at the top but if you click the connect link at the bottom, the the panel appears at the bottom.

Here is the code I am using but it is not working:

HTML:

```
<div class="one"><a href="#sidebar-connect">Show It</a></div>
<div class="two"><a href="#sidebar-connect">Display It</a></div>

<div id="sidebar-connect" class="widget-area cf">
    <div id="text-7" class="widget-1 widget-first widget-odd facebook widget widget_text">
    <h3 class="widget-title">Landmark Forum Grads on Facebook</h3>          
        <div class="textwidget">
        <p>Connect with Landmark friends near you and around the world. <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Landmark-Education/79075676234?v=box_3&amp;ref=ts#!/pages/Landmark-Education/79075676234?v=wall&ref=ts" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-widget','http://www.facebook.com']);" target=_blank />Follow Landmark  &gt;</a></p>
        <p>Get insights from Landmark Forum leaders—powerful, practical, profound. <a href="http://www.facebook.com/LandmarkInsights" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-widget','http://www.facebook.com']);" style="margin-top:0;" target=_blank />Follow Landmark Insights &gt;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="text-6" class="widget-2 widget-even insights widget widget_text">
    <h3 class="widget-title">Landmark Newsletter for Landmark Forum Grads</h3>
        <div class="textwidget">
        <p>Get powerful insights from Landmark Forum leaders direct to your inbox or on your phone. <a href="http://www.landmarkinsights.com" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-widget','http://www.landmarkinsights.com']);" target=_blank />Landmark Insights, a Landmark Newsletter &gt;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="pointer"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.two {
    float:left ;
    width:40% ;
}

.one {
    float:right ;
    width:40% ;
}


#sidebar-connect {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:33px;
    bottom:auto;
    left:-257px;
    width:270px;
    padding:10px;
    color:#41352f;
    background:#fff;
    font-size:10px;
    border:1px solid #bfb6a8;
    z-index:99;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
}

#sidebar-connect .pointer   {
    position:absolute;
    top:-6px;
    right:15px;
    display:block;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:#fff;
    border-top:1px solid #bfb6a8;
    border-right:1px solid #bfb6a8;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.7071067690849304, M12=0.7071067690849304, M21=-0.7071067690849304, M22=0.7071067690849304,sizingMethod='auto expand');
}

#sidebar-connect.bottom {
    top:auto;
    left:0;
    bottom:30px;
    box-shadow: 0 -3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
}

#sidebar-connect.bottom .pointer {
    left:15px;
    right:auto;
    top:auto;
    bottom:-6px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(135deg);
    transform:rotate(135deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=-0.7071067690849304, M12=-0.7071067690849304, M21=0.7071067690849304, M22=-0.7071067690849304,sizingMethod='auto expand');
}

#sidebar-connect .widget {
    margin:5px 0;
    padding:5px 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #bfb6a8;
    line-height:12px;
}

#sidebar-connect .widget:last-of-type   {
    border-bottom:none; margin-bottom:0;
}

#sidebar-connect .widget-title  {background-image:url('img/sprites.png'); overflow:hidden; text-indent:-999px; margin-bottom:5px;}
#sidebar-connect .widget p      {margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:0; text-transform: none;}
#sidebar-connect .widget a      {white-space:nowrap; font-size:10px; text-decoration:none;}
.blogs .textwidget              {background:url('img/sprites.png') 0 2px no-repeat; padding-left:55px; min-height:45px;} 
.blogs .widget-title            {background-position: 0 -93px; width: 106px; height: 13px;} 
.facebook .widget-title         {background-position: 0 -298px; width: 70px; height: 20px;} 
.facebook .textwidget p         {background:url('img/sprites.png') 0 -226px no-repeat; padding-left:25px; min-height:20px;}
.googleplus .widget-title       {background-position: 0 -368px; width: 60px; height: 20px;}
.insights .widget-title         {background-position: 0 -532px; width: 112px; height: 15px;}
.insights .textwidget           {background:url('img/sprites.png') 0 -438px no-repeat; padding-left:55px; min-height:45px;}
#text-5 .widget-title           {background-position:0 -597px; width: 71px; height: 21px;}
.youtube .widget-title          {background-position: 0 -733px; width: 47px; height: 17px;} 
.youtube .textwidget p          {background:url('img/sprites.png') 0 -666px no-repeat; padding-left:25px; min-height:19px;}
```

and the JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // Setup the Connect Box functionality
    jQuery("[href='#sidebar-connect']").showHideConnectBox();

    jQuery("#sidebar-connect").mouseleave(function() {
        jQuery("#sidebar-connect").stop(true,true).slideUp('fast').removeClass('show');
    });

});
```

Please help!

Comment: Could you post your relevant HTML and jQuery code?

Comment: if i am not wrong then you can simply use jQuery `accordion`. Because your 2nd and 3rd line points to that idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given your html, the following is a simple jquery script to move your sidebar

1. add `position:relative` to css for `.one` and `.two`
2. add a common class to your links - in this case I chose `link`
3. Add the following jquery to your `$(document).ready`

**jQuery**

```
var sidebar = $('#sidebar-connect');

$('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    sidebar.stop().hide().detach();
    $(this).append(sidebar);
    sidebar.slideDown();
});
```

**Example** http://jsfiddle.net/zg77u/2/

Comment: This is *almost* exactly what I need! The only thing missing is that there is no way to hide the panel once it is open, other than clicking the other link. If I click the first link to open the panel, clicking the first link again should hide it. Same w/ the second link.

Comment: Awesome! I was able to take what you did and build on it to do exactly what I needed. http://digitaldemo.net/landmark/ Thanks so much!